# Count order of overlapping date ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ms-access

I'm not sure if the title quite paints the correct picture, but I'll attempt to explain. I have a table with start and end dates, and team members IDs (sort of like projects). I need to determine when they overlap, count the number of overlaps, and determine the order of overlap (sorted by the start date). My dummy data should clarify, but it's the latter of the 3 that I really want. Here is my current table:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Team Member ║ Start Date ║  End Date  ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║           1 ║ 01/01/2015 ║ 04/01/2015 ║
║           1 ║ 04/01/2015 ║ 06/01/2015 ║
║           1 ║ 06/01/2015 ║ 07/01/2015 ║
║           2 ║ 04/01/2015 ║ 06/01/2015 ║
║           2 ║ 06/01/2015 ║ 10/01/2015 ║
║           3 ║ 01/01/2015 ║ 09/01/2015 ║
║           3 ║ 11/01/2015 ║ 13/01/2015 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

And here is what I want:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ OverlapOrder ║ Team Member ║ Start Date ║  End Date  ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║            0 ║           1 ║ 01/01/2015 ║ 04/01/2015 ║
║            1 ║           1 ║ 04/01/2015 ║ 06/01/2015 ║
║            0 ║           1 ║ 06/01/2015 ║ 07/01/2015 ║
║            0 ║           2 ║ 04/01/2015 ║ 06/01/2015 ║
║            1 ║           2 ║ 06/01/2015 ║ 10/01/2015 ║
║            0 ║           3 ║ 01/01/2015 ║ 09/01/2015 ║
║            0 ║           3 ║ 11/01/2015 ║ 13/01/2015 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

So you can see that team members shouldn't affect each other's overlap order.

I'm using Access SQL at the moment, but shortly moving to SQL Server, so a solution in either is the goal!

P.S. you'll see that the 2nd and 3rd data row have the same start date. The overlap order between these 2 is arbitrary; they can be either way round.

EDIT: Changed sample dataset so it covers a new highlighted possibility. The OverlapOrder column can go from 0 to however high depending on how many projects overlap.

Comment: So overlapOrder should start from 0 and increment for each overlap on each team member?If there is no overlap it stays 0?Also do you have a column to ORDER BY by?

Comment: This is going to get exceedingly difficult to do with only set-based SQL. Example: If you have 3 rows A, B, C, where A overlaps with B, B overlaps with C, but A does not overlap with C, I'm reading from your question that you want order 0, 1, 2, but to get all these rows into the same group you're going to have serious difficulties writing up any sort of JOIN clause or similar that will put them all into the same group.

Comment: I suppose in that case, A and C would be 0, and B would be 1. I was guessing this would be painfully hard to do. Order by columns would be team member, start date, end date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are able to migrate to SQL Server 2005 or above, you can try the below solution which uses CTEs to do something like what you want:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by startdate, enddate) rn
 from tbl)
select *, case when (datediff(dd,s.startdate,t.enddate) >= 0) then s.rn - 1 else 0 end
from cte s
left join cte t on s.id = t.id and t.rn = s.rn - 1
```

You should take this with a pinch of salt however, since this solution might well be engineered specifically to the sample data set. I have not tested it out with different cases yet.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OZK89019)

Comment: Upvoted as it solves the original solution. As Lasse V. Karlsen pointed out, it doesn't work if A overlaps with B, B overlaps with C, but A does not overlap with C. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: @marcus.d.johnson What would the expected results be in that case? I chose 3 ranges - 1 to 4, 3 to 8 and 7 to 9 of the same month, and it gave me the values 0,1,2. http://rextester.com/NTBZN21686

Comment: Yes so in that case, I would want 0,1,0

Comment: I see. I agree with the other commenters - there doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this, if you consider dependencies as in your updated sample. Perhaps it might be easier to do in the application layer?

Comment: Hmm, yes perhaps it would. Thanks anyway, I'll mark yours as the answer